# How to remove first line of jTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am quite new to programming and java.
I want to know how to remove first line on jtextarea.
Though I can post the coding of my application but I don't think it's needed and plus I am on phone.
Please tell me how to remove first line in jtextfield java.

Ok... heres the code for what I am trying to do->

```
String x = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
String z = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter new name for Database");
        try{
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection)
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+GlobalParams.portvar+"/",""+k,""+j);
        Statement stmnt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query3 = "Create database "+z;
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query3);
        String query = "use "+x;
        stmnt.executeQuery(query);
        String query2 = "show tables";
        Statement stmnt2 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmnt2.executeQuery(query2);
        while (rs.next()){ 
        String dname = rs.getString("Tables_in_"+x);
        if(jTextArea1.getText().equals("")){
        jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+dname);
        }
        else{
            jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+"\n"+dname);
        }
        String y = jTextArea1.getText();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(y);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String query4 =  "RENAME TABLE "+x+"."+line+" TO "+z+"."+line;
        //I will add remove first line code here.--------------------------------------
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query4);
        String query5 = "drop database "+x;
        stmnt.executeUpdate(query5);
}}}

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to create a program which renames databases in mysql. It works fine but it moves just one table and then it gives error that "table already exists (same table name that it moved)" in new database. Since it gets the table names from lines present in textarea, i suspect its reading same line again and again. So my idea is to remove the first line everytime the code is completed so that it wont take the same table name twice.
To be clear what I want to do->
Suppose my text area consists of following lines->

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
so on...
```

I want that after execution of code, line 1 should be removed and the new text present in textarea should be->

```
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
so on...
```

Comment: We generally dont like to just post the answer willy nilly. Please get home and post what you have tried, and then we will help you from there. Also I dont really know what you mean by remove the first line, hence the need for code.

Comment: ok ok... please dont give soooo many thumb downs :o I am new to programming and this site and I really have extremely little idea how things go here. Anyways, I editted my post and added details you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `scanner.nextLine()` after creating the `Scanner`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(y);
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) // Skips first line
    scanner.nextLine();
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually sir, I just tested this command now from all aspects (earlier I was in hurry and just checked if it gave an exception or not) and I just noticed that it just copies last table (say if my database has 3 tables, table1/table2/table3; then it only copies table 3). So I think the only better way is to remove the first line from textarea after every execution. So please tell me the command to remove the first line from textarea.

Comment: @user2828458, just call `scanner.nextLine()` each time you want to skip a line. But I think you should go back to paper and think more thoroughly on how what you want to do and how you plan to do it. It's always helpful to write/draw before running into the code. ;)

Comment: Thanks again sir. You were a big help. Though I finally discovered a way to remove first line. The following code can be used for purpose->   int end = jTextArea1.getLineEndOffset(0);
jTextArea1.replaceRange("", 0, end); This code will automatically erase first line.